# What approach should be used to manage Redis keys in a Java project

Tags: java, data-structures, redis, architecture, software-design

In redis projects, when the project is getting bigger, the number of keys also increases. I prefer to keep all keys in one central place and use them from wherever they are needed.

I keep all the key generation process in one class called RedisKeys and use them with its static methods.

Here is an example :

```
 public static String USER_PREFIX = "usr";

    public static String getUserKeyTemplate() {
        return USER_PREFIX + ":@id:json";
    }

    public static String getUserKey(String id) {
        return USER_PREFIX + ":" + id + ":json";
    }

    public static String getUserListKey() {
        return USER_PREFIX;
    }

    public static String getUserNickSetKey() {
        return USER_PREFIX + "set";
    }

    public static String getPasswordKey(String email) {
        return USER_PREFIX + "mail:" + email + ":pass";
    }

    public static String getUserIdFromEmailKey(String email) {
        return USER_PREFIX + "mail:" + email + ":uid";
    }

    public static String getUserKey(int userId) {
        return getUserKey(userId + "");
    }


    public static String getUserNameKey(String userName) {
        return USER_PREFIX + "name:" + userName + ":uid";
    }
```

Given methods represent the all keys that will be used for user operations. For example if I need to ask Redis to get user password, I do the following :

```
String key = RedisKeys.getPasswordKey("test@test.com");
```

The value of key variable would be `usr:mail:test@test.com:pass`, then I can send a GET command to Redis with this.

However, as you can see it seems too ugly. An `Enum` like approach sounds good, but the keys are not CONSTANT values. They stand as templates to generate the right key.

What approach do you offer to manage the keys with dynamic key generation in better way ?

Comment: Create an `enum` that `implements Function<String, String>`. Or `Function<Object[], String>` if you need more than one parameter.

Comment: Anything different than enum can be applied as a design pattern to this problem ?